# What kind of fan connector is this?

Tags: connector, pins, fan

I need to change fans of my beamer but I cant find a replacement because I dont know which connector they used. 
Thought it would be an 3 Pin connector but it isnt.

The connector in the pictures is 5x5x2,5mm

Hope anyone can help me!

[image]

[image]

Comment: At a first guess it's either a Molex or Hirose part. Are there any markings visible, probably on the top (wire entry) side?

Comment: @PhilG I can read C 600V VW-1 HC-D (02.0/1.0)

Comment: @combi35 Is that code is on the wire? Or on the connector itself?

Comment: Show the end view of the connectors, include a ruler or banana for scale, and crop down the original high res photos to zoom in on the useful part before you upload so that maximum clarity is preserved when the website scales the photo.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a lot like a Molex PicoBlade 0510210300:

https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0510210300_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml

[image]